# htaccess file rewrite error - ^trip/(\d+)*$ ./trip.html?tripId=$1

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im new to using htaccess, i have created an .htaccess file in project folder (im running it with xampp on localhost if it cahnges anything).

I have the following in the file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^trip/(\d+)*$ ./trip.html?tripId=$1
```

And what i want to get is that i could access localhost:8000/trip/1 and it will be the same as localhost:8000/trip.html?tripId=1

But i keep getting "cannot get /trip/1 for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Gabi.

Comment: Do you have 'AllowOverride All' in your apache config?

Comment: it seems like my htaccess is not working at all, i tried adding junk at the start of the file to get internal server error but it still works...

Comment: Then you don't have it in the right place. Paste your apache config in the question

Comment: The bigger problem is that you're adding a query string to a static file and then hiding it. Unless you've set the `html` extension to be parsed as a server-side language, the named `tripId` variable will never exist to client-side script. It will only be able to get the number from `location.pathname`

Comment: Pasting the all config file is probably too much, but i do have this line:LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so which i think should be enough no? And walf i didnt understand you, what do you mean im adding a query string to a static file then hiding it? And why would the tripId variable will never exists? How else would you change the /trip.html/?tripId=1 to /trip/1 ?

Comment: You're doing an internal redirect so that query is only available to server-side code. A static file can't do anything with a query on the server, it can only do something in JS, client side, and the client-side URL has no query.